# Custom mobile button icon with transparency issue

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, background-image

I am using a circular `.png` with transparency as a custom button icon, but am seeing a square, semi-transparent background around the icon on the Android 4.2.2 browser. It seems to be displaying as expected in all of the browsers that we are targeting, including on the Android 4.1.2 default web browser (tested with Samsung Galaxy S2), except for the Android 4.2.2 default web browser (tested with Samsung Galaxy S4).

**Screenshots:**

(Bug)
[image: Bug - Android 4.2.2 Default Web Browser]
(Expected)
[image: Expected - Chrome for Desktop]

**jsFiddle**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xRpeb/1/) is a jsFiddle that demonstrates this issue. It is a stripped version of my full code, but I have tested and verified that the issue does occur with this demo (Samsung Galaxy S4).

**CSS:**

```
.ui-icon-main-nav {
    background-image: url(/presentation/generic/includes/images/mobile/main-nav-icon.png);
    -moz-background-size: 17px 17px;
    -o-background-size: 17px 17px;
    -webkit-background-size: 17px 17px;
    background-size: 17px 17px;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
...
<!-- ui-icon-main-nav is created by jQuery Mobile -->
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-main-nav">&nbsp;</span>
...
```

Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

Thank you all for your help. :)

Comment: Seems like it's behaving the same way IE6 does when rendering transparent png's. Could you try optimizing it with [ImageOptim (OSX)](http://imageoptim.com/) or [PNGGauntlet (Windows)](http://pnggauntlet.com/)?

Comment: Can you add more of your code, basically add everything we need to take a look recreate your problem seen in pictures (including a listview).

Comment: @Gajotres - I am trying to create a jsFiddle right now. Adding more of the actual code is a bit of a no-no, as this is for a client's site.

Comment: I understand, I would just like to see actual button, I think I understand your problem but I wasn't been able to recreate it with your current example.

Comment: @Gajotres - I have added the fiddle. I apologize for the delay; I had to strip out any references to the client, add the resources and verify that the demo does reproduce the issue (which it does - see above for more).

Comment: @JohnKlakegg - Thank you for the suggestions, but, unfortunately, image optimization is not an option with this implementation.

Comment: No problem. I don't have that device at hand, but could you check [this fiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net/aK2dM/1/), if it works I would guess it might be a bug with rendering 24-bit png. Tried to do some searching on the topic but results were limited, sorry.

Comment: @JohnKlakegg - Thank you for your help. As it turns out, this issue was caused by a different bug on Android. See my solution, below. I am surprised that this issue is not more notorious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery Mobile adds a semi-transparent background and a `border-radius` to the icons (`.ui-icon`). There is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245624) on Android 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean), in which the background color of an element displays outside of the element's border when the `border-radius` property is specified. A comment on the ticket states that the issue "seems to be fixed in the current beta (29.0.1547.23)", however this fix may not appear in a wide-spread roll-out for some time.

The CSS fix for this issue is to set the `background` property of the icon to `none` before setting the `background-image`.

Here is the updated CSS style:

```
.ui-icon-main-nav {
    background: none;
    background-image: url(/presentation/generic/includes/images/mobile/main-nav-icon.png);
    -moz-background-size: 17px 17px;
    -o-background-size: 17px 17px;
    -webkit-background-size: 17px 17px;
    background-size: 17px 17px;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xRpeb/2/).

This is an unfortunate issue, as the only resolution is to remove the background color, or add the background color into the image, itself.